# Unexpected Identifier when reading txt file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in node, I want to create
a list data structure from reading a txt file, here is my code to read the file.

```
        var fs = require("fs");
        var filename = require("../films.txt");
        
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err,data){
          var contents = data;
          var splitContents = contents.split("\n");
          var string = JSON.stringify(splitContents);
          console.log(string)
        });
```

And below this line is the text file I want to read is 20 movies, the name of the file is films.txt.

```
    1. The Shawshank Redemption
    2. The Godfather
    3. The Godfather: Part II
    4. Pulp Fiction
    5. The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
    6. 12 Angry Men
    7. Schindler’s List
    8. The Dark Knight
    9. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
    10. Fight Club
    11. Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back
    12. One Flew Over the Cuckoo’s Nest
    13. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
    14. Inception
    15. Goodfellas
    16. Star Wars
    17. Seven Samurai
    18. The Matrix
    19. Forrest Gump
    20. City of God
```

Every single time I run the program and console.log the contents I get the same error

> ```
> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 1. The Shawshank Redemption
>
>                                                               ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
>     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>
>     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>
>     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>
>     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> ```

I will appreciate the feedback on what I am doing wrong, thank you

Comment: When you see _compile in the runstack it indicates a syntax issue, meaning your javascript isn't properly formed (missing bracket etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
var filename = require("../films.txt");
```

should be this:

```
var filename = "../films.txt";
```

`filename` should be the path to your file. `require` are used to load modules (which are valid javascript code not movie list).

Answer (score 2):

`require` loads a file as if it is Javascript code, attempting to run it. Your text file is not Javascript code. You simply want to do this:

```
    var fs = require("fs");
    var filename = "../films.txt";

    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err,data){
      // ...
```

Comment: @Dark Falcon what is the difference between require and the regular way in this case?

Comment: What do you mean "the regular way"?